# I want to fetch "Linux Timestamp" for the Specified date and use it as a parameter in my JMeter test plan

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am currently using '${__time()}' function which returns the current time in milliseconds. However, I want something like this - Date Input 'mm/dd/yyyy' and Function Output '1504290600'. can somebody please help me.
Note: I want output as Linux time and not in other formats as other questions already have.

Answer (score 1):

Out of box JMeter doesn't provide this functionality, you will need a custom script for this, I would recommend using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or [Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function for this

Example code would be something like:

```
${__groovy(new Date().parse("MM/dd/yyyy"\, "09/04/2017").getTime(),)}
```

Or in case of non-functions:

```
def timestamp = new Date().parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "09/04/2017").getTime()
log.info('Required time is: ' + timestamp)
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Convert Time]

- Replace `09/04/2017` with the date of your choice
- Remember that month pattern is capital `M`, lower case `m` is for minutes. See [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class reference for details
- The above construction is available due to [Groovy JDK Enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/), you won't be able to use it in Java or Beanshell
- See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks, it works!